# Python pandas read_csv - Loading tgz-zipped dataset in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load the "California Housing" dataset into a pandas dataframe directly from the source URL. The URL points to a tgz-file that contains two files, cal_housing.data and cal_housing.domain.

Loading the file with pandas read_csv is working fine but it makes one error that I don't understand and want to get rid off: The first value of the dataframe (first row, first column) is replaced by the filename.

This is what cal_housing.data looks like:

```
0 -122.230000,37.880000,41.000000,880.000000,129.000000,322.000000,126.000000,8.325200,452600.000000
1 -122.220000,37.860000,21.000000,7099.000000,1106.000000,2401.000000,1138.000000,8.301400,358500.000000
2 -122.240000,37.850000,52.000000,1467.000000,190.000000,496.000000,177.000000,7.257400,352100.000000
3 ...
```

This is what cal_housing.domain looks like:

```
0 longitude: continuous.
1 latitude: continuous.
2 housingMedianAge: continuous. 
3 totalRooms: continuous. 
4 totalBedrooms: continuous. 
5 population: continuous. 
6 households: continuous. 
7 medianIncome: continuous. 
8 medianHouseValue: continuous.
```

This is what I do:

```py
import pandas as pd
source = 'http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.tgz'
col_names = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'housingMedianAge', 'totalRooms', 'totalBedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'medianIncome', 'medianHouseValue']
data = pd.read_csv(source, compression='gzip', header=None, names=col_names).dropna()
print(type(data))
```

This is what I get:

```
0      CaliforniaHousing/cal_housing.data     37.88              41.0   ...
1                             -122.220000     37.86              21.0   ...
2                             -122.240000     37.85              52.0   ...
...
```

And finally, this is what I want to get:

```
0      -122.230000     37.88              41.0   ...
1      -122.220000     37.86              21.0   ...
2      -122.240000     37.85              52.0   ...
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some playing around, I found a solution. It's much more complicated than what I hoped for... so please feel free to post better solutions, if you find them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import tarfile
import urllib.request
source = 'http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.tgz'
col_names = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'housingMedianAge', 'totalRooms', 'totalBedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'medianIncome', 'medianHouseValue']
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=urllib.request.urlopen(source), mode="r|gz")
for member in tar:
    if 'data' in member.name: 
        content = tar.extractfile(member).read()
        data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(content), encoding='utf8', header=None, names=col_names)
print(data)
```

And this is what I get:

```
0      -122.230000     37.88              41.0   ...
1      -122.220000     37.86              21.0   ...
2      -122.240000     37.85              52.0   ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

> compression : {‘infer’, ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’, None}, default
>   ‘infer’ For on-the-fly decompression of on-disk data. If ‘infer’, then
>   use gzip, bz2, zip or xz if filepath_or_buffer is a string ending in
>   ‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, ‘.zip’, or ‘xz’, respectively, and no decompression
>   otherwise. If using ‘zip’, the ZIP file must contain only one data
>   file to be read in. Set to None for no decompression. New in version
>   0.18.1: support for ‘zip’ and ‘xz’ compression.

I don't see tarballs in the list. It seems that you're trying to use 'gzip' on a gzipped tarball. I recommend extracting the files locally and reading the dataframes from the separate csv files.

Comment: It's exactly what I don't want to do. I found a solution. See below.

Comment: You said you didn't understand why you were seeing what you were seeing and the answer is that tgz isn't supported. You didn't provide any information about what other constraints you had or why you don't want to extract files locally.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I wrote "directly from the URL". For me, that means exactly that. You are right, that it doesn't seem to support this file type, but it looked a lot like it did when I looked at the result and I thought a simple parameter might change it. I haven't found that parameter, so I build something more complicated.